# Dragula Drag only wanted elements

Tags: angular, dragula, ng2-dragula

Here is my component.html

```
<div class="row" [dragula]='"photos-bag"' [dragulaModel]='photos'>
    <div *ngFor="let photo of photos" [class.sortable]="photo.sortable">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail" > 
            <img src="http://placehold.it/140.png" > 
        </a>
        {{ photo.name }}
    </div>                                                                                                                                                                                                      
</div>
```

and here is the part in my component.ts which set the element to be draggable if it contains a sortable class

```
dragulaService.setOptions('photos-bag', {
    moves: function(el, source, handle, sibling) {
            return el.classList.contains('sortable');
        },
});
```

Now here is the problem.. is there an option to only switch elements that has the `sortable` class?.. So far I thought accepts/invalid option will do the trick but it seems not.

Answer (score 0):

Insted using [class.sortable]="photo.sortable"  use **[className]="cssClass(photo)"**

**.html**

```
<div class="row" [dragula]='"photos-bag"' [dragulaModel]='photos'>
    <div *ngFor="let photo of photos" [className]="cssClass(photo)>
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail" > 
            <img src="" > 
        </a>
        {{ photo.name }}
    </div>                                                                                                                                                                                                      
</div>
```

**.ts file**

```
cssClass(photo){
   // based on condition return "draggable CSS" or **Non draggable CSS** 
}
```

**DragulaService**

```
dragulaService.setOptions('photos-bag', {
    moves: function(el, source, handle, sibling) {
           return el.className === "draggableCSS"?true:false
        },
});
```

if still not working create plunker.